# How does one usually go about security trimming RIA services results?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf, ria

With RIA services, you easily end up exposing quite a few service operations, many of which ought to imply business specific (contextual) security considerations.

Storing the current user in a session or similar, and figuring out who he/she represents on each query operation is all well and good; but is this the common / best way of going about things?

I'd very much appreciate some guidance on best practices here :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the checking has to be done by something, so you might as well use the standard membership/role providers (or your own replacements).

You can attribute the RIA services methods with [required roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.requiresroleattribute%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) (e.g. using `[RequiresRole("RoleName")]`) then the checks are not handled explicitly by you.

Comment: Blocking operations entirely is one thing. What I figure I have to do is trim the data returned (some items should be viewable / writable by user X, others shouldn't). Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @GraceP: Are you talking about just specific properties of data objects being suppressed?

Comment: Example: _User A, of Branch 1, shouldn't be able to see documents owned by Branch 2_. Just your normal run of the mill permission trimming. I'm really just wondering if theres a common way of doing this with the plethora of operations generated by RIA/EF, or if I should just roll my own.